# Cassandra repair taking forever and increasing disk usage

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

My team is using Apache Cassandra 3.0, not DSE, for our 10 node cluster. We have one DC and all nodes are 1 TB each. 
Right now all the nodes are around 300 GB occupied, The RF is 2. We have not run anti-entropy (manual) repair in a long time. The problem I am facing now is that I started repair on one of the nodes and it is taking forever. Is that normal? Also, the repair failed once and I am noticing increase in the disk space for that node, it is ~400GB now. how can I fix this behavior?

Comment: can you include the command your running to do the repair? its likely incremental repair which will not work if you havent run in long time.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I ran "nodetool repair" on that node and have been looking at netstats and compactionstats.

Comment: It shows that the node has to transfer ~39GB data to its replica.

Comment: Starting repair command #1 (<id>), repairing keyspace <name> with repair options (parallelism: parallel, primary range: false, incremental: true, job threads: 1, ColumnFamilies: [], dataCenters: [], hosts: [], # of ranges: 511, pull repair: false)

Answer (score 1):

incremental repairs will not work in this scenario (default repairs). They have been meant to run from beginning so it never covers too much data. I would strongly recommend using sub range repairs - this can be a little difficult but can be automated with OpsCenters repair service or [Reaper](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-reaper)

Answer (score 0):

you can use nodetool repair -pr -full
-pr will help node only repair the data range where it owns;
-full will disable the incremental repair and like other people suggests, incremental repair is not a good fit